# How To Scale Stroke Width For SVG In Sketch?

Tags: vector, svg, images, sketch-app

I created this image in Sketch using two rectangles and a circle:

This is what is looks like with a width of 135px and height of 102px:

[image]

When I scale it I would like it to look EXACTLY the same, just bigger.

However, this is what it looks like at 400px width:

[image]

The line width does not change at all, and this makes them look proportionately much thinner than they are in the smaller image.

It gets worse the more you scale it:

[image]

I would think there should be some way to control this in Sketch. I have looked all through the options in the panel, tried flattening and converting the shapes to something else, but I cannot figure it out...

Can anyone please show me to make it so the stroke widths scale as I scale this svg image?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I was holding shift, clicking the corner, and dragging, but it seems like this is this just a different tool than the ones I should have used.

Instead, I selected my whole object and then used the **scale** tool to scale my vector image while keeping the stroke proportional.

[image]

If things are off when you scale, try hitting ctrl+g to group everything first. happy designing.

Comment: Hi. Don't forget you can choose your own answer as best if this is now solved.